# Server status 400 blocks json from sending response to client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, post, axios

I'm currently developing client side for my app.
When i try to login user in case where email and password is correct everything works fine but sending error data isn't occuring because `status(400)` blocks it.

Here is part of my server side code for user login that isn't sending object with `isAuth, message, err`:

```
User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, user) => {
        if (!user) return res.status(400).json({
            isAuth: false,
            message: "Auth failed, bad email",
            err
        })
```

But when I make it like that i get the error with all parameters:

```
User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, user) => {
        if (!user) return res.json({
            isAuth: false,
            message: "Auth failed, bad email",
            err
        })
```

**Another strange thing is that when I send bad request with Postman I'm getting all the response data.**

And here is client side function that is making request, the `console.log(request)` part is blocked because of status 400:

```
    const submitForm = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const request = await axios.post('/api/login', { email: email, password: password }).then(res => res.data)
        console.log(request)

        dispatch({
            type: "USER_LOGIN",
            payload: request
        })
    }
```

And here is some of Chrome stuff from console:

```
xhr.js:166 POST http://localhost:3000/api/login 400 (Bad Request)
createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

Comment: Try err: err in returning object

Comment: delete res.status(400) to read the response, some library blocks  not 200 responses and you can read the Err, or i suggest to you to console.log(err) before send response

Comment: `err` will be `null` unless there is an actual error.The `!user` merely tests that the `user` is `null`, which is **not** an **error**. MongoDB does not consider "not found" to be an error. Only actual read/network errors would be reported here. AFAIK express has no problem sending a custom body on a `400` status ( probably should be `404`, but I digress ). Not certain on the axios side.

Comment: @NeilLunn about error stuff you are right of course. err object from express post call is null. And with the axios stuff it looks like console.log under axios isn't read at all because it should give undefined or something.

Comment: @MohammadSadeghForoughi Yup you are right, status 200 triggers send function and I get the response. 404 to blocks the request. Do you have any idea which library is causing such behavios? Is sending 200 on bad request in my case is something that needs to be fixed?

Comment: @MMaicki add status in you'r API, status:true for success and status:false is for errors, in case of errors log the error, please note don't send Error to the client, it will create a vulnerability.

Comment: @MohammadSadeghForoughi I have done it for now but it's strange bahavior, on every topic about `status` and `send` there is syntax just as mine and it works everywhere...

Comment: technically you response will blocked in network layer, when you use a cloud service , it will watch and modify you're responses. in first look it's not good behavior but it's good for network and maintenance analyst system. @MMaicki

Answer (score 0):

There was an axios error/bug.

I have rewrited my code using `fetch` API. It seems that axios has some kind of bug when it comes to handling 4xx and 5xx status.

Now client part looks like this:

```
const submitForm = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const request = await fetch('/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }).then(res => res.json())

        console.log(request)

        dispatch({
            type: "USER_LOGIN",
            payload: request
        })
    }
```

At the server side everything is just as it should be, `return res.status(400).send(data)`